# Seasonal weights of a time series: stl function versus subtracting average values

Tags: r, time-series, mean, seasonality, loess

Say that we are dealing with a time series of 25 years of daily measurements of a variable with seasonal cycles, e.g. it reaches higher values in winter than in summer.

The objective is to compute the *monthly weights* that produce the seasonal oscillation. Let's say that the amplitude of the cycles does not seem to increase over time, so we assume this time series as being *additive*. 
[image]

I can identify two approaches:

1. Use R's function [stl](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/stl.html), which performs a seasonal decomposition by LOESS, access the `$time.series[,"seasonal"]` object to retrieve the weights, and then subtract these weights from the daily values belonging to the relevant month;
2. Compute the monthly average of the observed variable over the entire time series, and subtract them to each daily value of the relevant month.

I know the general consensus is to use option 1 because it has long been used and it has publications backing it up, but from a theoretical point of view, **why should one use option 1?** And roughly speaking, **what is the real difference between the two options, especially considering that they can produce hugely different weights?**